# Euphemism for weasel-like

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means 'weasilish', but similar to equine, aquiline, etc.

The best I could come up with is mustelidic.  Maybe mustelidine?  I need it as an adjective:  "mustelidic communications."

The context I need to use it in is a bit of a joke about using weasel words.  Using 'weaselish' doesn't work because it is too forthright.

It doesn't have to be strict English -- can be a word made up based on the latin word for weasel and existing English rules.  I'm just looking for something that sounds reasonable, obscure, but is also precise.

Comment: 'mustelidic/-ine' would be a euphemism rather than a weasel-word for weasel.

Comment: I'll change the question to that.  You're right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'We can play outside the rules of the English language'.

Comment: there may be overlap. A [euphemism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) hides or obscures, usually for vulgarity but also bluntness or pedestrianess (?) (vulgar as in gross and also as in common). A [weasel-word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word), is just a modifier that makes things weaker, so that if taken literally, one can't be held to saying the full sense (e.g. almost, kind of, I think, partially, etc).

Comment: So you want a weasel word for "weasel like"?

Comment: How about a secondary derivation, akin to Cockney rhyming slang, calling them _ickle Ronniekins_ words or perhaps _Won-Won_ words (both from nicknames given to the Harry Potter character Ron _Weasley_) or _Wetherby_ words (from what said Ron’s brother Percy was frequently called by his erstwhile employer [who was, to be fair, being mind-controlled by someone else])? Fairly obscure, I’d say, but perhaps not overly precise.

Comment: @HotLicks In short, I want to refer to something as weasel-like, without saying that outright.  I want to use a euphemism (or weasel-word) itself to refer to something as weasel-like.  I admit, it's a bit recursive, but that's the intended joke.  Musteline is perfect.  I thought I'd have to make up a word based on the latin, like 'mustelidic'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Musteline* seems a bit too direct; everybody would know what you meant.

Try *tergiversating* or *tergiversatory* instead: it means shifty or crafty.  There is a verb *tergiversate* and a noun *tergiversation* to go with it. Per the OED, *tergiversation* is:

> 1. The action of ‘turning one’s back on’, i.e. forsaking, something in which one was previously engaged, interested, or concerned; desertion or abandonment of a cause, party, etc.; apostasy, renegation. Also with *a* and *pl.*, an instance of this; an act of desertion or apostasy.
> 2. Turning in a dishonourable manner from straightforward action or statement; shifting, shuffling, equivocation, prevarication. Also with *a* and *pl.*, an instance of this; an evasion, a subterfuge.

You want sense two.

When Hamlet was avoiding coming with Polonius at his lady mother’s behest by arguing whether a cloud was more like unto a camel or a weasel, the Prince was tergiversating — normally Polonius’s job.

Comment: I want the actual weasel animal to be in the word's derivation.  Musteline is it.  And it's even a real word!

Answer (score 1):

*vulpine*, perhaps? It's not the same animal, but this word could work if your trying to imply some of the general physical features. It also covers some of the same qualities associated with weasels: cunning, sneakiness, slinking, thieving, etc.

Comment: Thank you, it's a good suggestion, but in my case the word deriving back to an actual weasel is required.